# .loc indexing in Pandas-Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am having and issue with indexing of some columns. when i try indexing like that on python:

```
list(df1.loc[:,1980:1987])
```

I get the following error:
TypeError: cannot do slice indexing on  with these indexers [1980] of

If i try it like that:

```
list(df1.loc[:,'1980':'1987'])
```

I get the following error:

KeyError: '1980'

The dtype is float64. I want to be able to call the column label which i a year for columns 1980-1987 and drop those but without calling the index column number but the label.

Thank you

Comment: Not sure of the exact issue. But quick fix would be `df1.select(lambda x:1980<=x<1987)`

Comment: Can you provide a self-contained example demonstrating the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Slicing works on columns whatever their type. See the examples below. Maybe, you have to check your data and / or provide us an example.

```
# Test data
df = pd.DataFrame({'1980': ['A', 'B'], 
                   '1981': ['A', 'B'], 
                   '1982': ['A', 'B']})

# With string
print(df.columns.dtype)
print(df.loc[:,'1980':'1981'])

# object
#   1980 1981
# 0    A    A
# 1    B    B

# With integer
df.columns = df.columns.astype('int')
print(df.columns.dtype)
print(df.loc[:,1980:1981])

# int64
#   1980 1981
# 0    A    A
# 1    B    B

# With float
df.columns = df.columns.astype('float')
print(df.columns.dtype)
print(df.loc[:,1980:1981])

# float64
#   1980.0 1981.0
# 0      A      A
# 1      B      B
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the answer my datatable looks like that:                        2064  2065  2066  2067 2068 2069 2070  
0  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  
1  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  
2  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN

Comment: When i run  print(df1.loc[:,2060:2062]) I get the following message: TypeError: cannot do slice indexing on <class 'pandas.indexes.base.Index'> with these indexers [2060] of <class 'int'>

Comment: And the dtypes is: 2060                         float64
2061                         float64
2062                         float64
2063                         float64
2064                         float64
2065                         float64
2066                         float64
2067                         float64
2068                         float64
2069                         float64
2070                         float64